# How to access hidden linux folders in a java file chooser

Tags: java, linux, jfilechooser, hidden-files

When you're in a java app and you use it's built-in file chooser, how can i view/access the hidden items in a LINUX directory

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You should try

```
fileChooser.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't mean to program it that way. I just want to know if there is a way to access them even if the option is set to true.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be useful to you:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know the hidden folder name or full path, just submit it in `File Name` field - then you will see the hidden folder contents.

For example, submit `.src` to go to hidden subdirectory `.src`.